# HTML select value assign to html field

Tags: html

I need a little help (i can`t figure out). How i can put a selected HTMl field value to another HTMl field when i select some value from the first field.

[image: Explanation of the problem in picutre]

Best regards
Trajce Gogov

Comment: So are you trying to put the selected value to multiple inputs when you select the value in one input?

Comment: You can do that with JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp. Could you make a jsFiddle of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Javascript solution could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdownList");
var dropdownListValue = document.getElementById("dropdownListValue");

if(dropdownList != null) {
    dropdownList.innerHTML = dropdownListValue;
}
</script>
```

Not proof-tested so not entirely sure if working. However, make sure you put it at the bottom of your page to allow everything load up and run BEFORE the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript   :

```
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">

 function show(){
  var combo=document.getElementById('combo1')
 document.form.yourtextboxname.value = combo.value 


 </SCRIPT >
```

set your `textbox` name and `dropdown/combobox` name, and put onChange like :

```
<select name=combo1 onChange='show()'>
```